# losing data with merge

Tags: pandas, join, merge

I try to combine two dataframes with the following code:

```
data = data.merge(test_data, on=['Date','About'], how='left')
```

data columns:

```
Date About Duration_training RPE_training ...
```

test_data columns:

```
Date About T-test Yoyo Heart_Rate(max)....
```

I want to combine these two dataframes into one.
The data dataframe consists of all the days that the players had a training. So almost all days
The test-data dataframe consists of all information about test we do a few times a year.

The problem is now that in some cases, a test was performed on a day that there was no training. Therefore the information of that day get's lost.

I tried all options off merge and join but can't find a way that it is working how i would

Comment: maybe `how="outer"` in the merge call?

Comment: Using `how="left"` will keep the rows from the first dataframe and merge the overlaps from the second dataframe. The rest will be thrown away. Try out `how="right"`, `how="inner"` and `how="outer"` and check the results.

Comment: I tried them all and nothing seems to work

Comment: I tried them all again and outer seems to work! thanks ♥